# Using foreach loop inside adaptive cards

Tags: botframework, chatbot, adaptive-cards

I have an adaptive card code base, I want to feed in data from an API end point which I have to loop through and setup inside a table or whatever best possible way if that can be done.

I have an adaptive card where I see table results want to add it row by row from a prebaked json dataset. Please help me.

Here is my code and what I am trying to do right now.

```
{
  "$kind": "Microsoft.AdaptiveDialog",
  "$designer": {
    "id": "ye84qG",
    "name": "AzureCodeSignAllErrorListAndMitigationDialog",
    "comment": "It will contain the list of errors and their mitigation."
  },
  "autoEndDialog": true,
  "defaultResultProperty": "dialog.result",
  "triggers": [
    {
      "$kind": "Microsoft.OnBeginDialog",
      "$designer": {
        "name": "BeginDialog",
        "description": "",
        "id": "8Nagxu"
      },
      "actions": [
        {
          "$kind": "Microsoft.SetProperty",
          "$designer": {
            "id": "dXShMa"
          },
          "property": "dialog.errors",
          "value": {
            "errorDetails": [
              {
                "Error": "Error 1",
                "Solution": "Thomas"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "$kind": "Microsoft.SendActivity",
          "$designer": {
            "id": "ayrtTW"
          },
          "activity": "${SendActivity_ayrtTW()}"
        },
        {
          "$kind": "Microsoft.SendActivity",
          "$designer": {
            "id": "iplD4r"
          },
          "activity": "${SendActivity_iplD4r()}"
        },
        {
          "$kind": "Microsoft.EndDialog",
          "$designer": {
            "id": "Oo0EWe"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "$kind": "Microsoft.OnUnknownIntent",
      "$designer": {
        "id": "AlFhWf",
        "name": "Unknown intent"
      },
      "actions": [
        {
          "$kind": "Microsoft.SendActivity",
          "$designer": {
            "id": "WqxJpj"
          },
          "activity": "${SendActivity_WqxJpj()}"
        },
        {
          "$kind": "Microsoft.EndDialog",
          "$designer": {
            "id": "OzOG0K"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "generator": "blabla.lg",
  "recognizer": "blabla.lu.qna",
  "id": "blablaDialog"
}




{
  "$kind": "Microsoft.AdaptiveDialog",
  "$designer": {
    "id": "ye84qG",
    "name": "AzureCodeSignAllErrorListAndMitigationDialog",
    "comment": "It will contain the list of errors and their mitigation."
  },
  "autoEndDialog": true,
  "defaultResultProperty": "dialog.result",
  "triggers": [
    {
      "$kind": "Microsoft.OnBeginDialog",
      "$designer": {
        "name": "BeginDialog",
        "description": "",
        "id": "8Nagxu"
      },
      "actions": [
        {
          "$kind": "Microsoft.SetProperty",
          "$designer": {
            "id": "dXShMa"
          },
          "property": "dialog.errors",
          "value": {
            "errorDetails": [
              {
                "Error": "Error 1",
                "Solution": "Thomas"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "$kind": "Microsoft.SendActivity",
          "$designer": {
            "id": "ayrtTW"
          },
          "activity": "${SendActivity_ayrtTW()}"
        },
        {
          "$kind": "Microsoft.SendActivity",
          "$designer": {
            "id": "iplD4r"
          },
          "activity": "${SendActivity_iplD4r()}"
        },
        {
          "$kind": "Microsoft.EndDialog",
          "$designer": {
            "id": "Oo0EWe"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "$kind": "Microsoft.OnUnknownIntent",
      "$designer": {
        "id": "AlFhWf",
        "name": "Unknown intent"
      },
      "actions": [
        {
          "$kind": "Microsoft.SendActivity",
          "$designer": {
            "id": "WqxJpj"
          },
          "activity": "${SendActivity_WqxJpj()}"
        },
        {
          "$kind": "Microsoft.EndDialog",
          "$designer": {
            "id": "OzOG0K"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "generator": "blabla.lg",
  "recognizer": "blabla.lu.qna",
  "id": "blablaDialog"
   }
```